Access Azure App Configuration from unit test project ran from Azure DevOps pipeline
I am deploying a new project in Azure Pipeline, I have unit tests into this projects. unit tests must have access an azure app configuration, what is the best way for my project to authenticate to access azure app configuration ?
I don't know how to use the managed identity from there ...

I read a little bit more and it appear managed identity is only used for VM which I don't want.
To be able to authenticate to Azure AppConfiguration from my unit test ran by my pipeline, I have used Azurecli task which has the ServiceConnection context and I ran dotnet test command, then I export my test results and my code coverage so that Azure DevOps has everything it needs
  - task: AzureCLI@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'devops-serviceconnection-dev'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        cd .\SharepointFileTransfer.Test\
        dotnet add package coverlet.collector
        dotnet test --logger "trx;LogFileName=TestResults.trx" --results-directory $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/TestResults --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"

  - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
    inputs:
      summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*coverage.cobertura.xml'
      failIfCoverageEmpty: false

  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    inputs:
      testResultsFormat: 'VSTest'
      testResultsFiles: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/TestResults/*.trx'
      mergeTestResults: true
      failTaskOnFailedTests: true

and then I used AzureCliCredential for my unit test to access to Azure AppConfiguration
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
{
    var visualStudioCredential = new VisualStudioCredential(new VisualStudioCredentialOptions() { TenantId = TenantId });
    var tokenCredential = new ChainedTokenCredential(visualStudioCredential, new AzureCliCredential(), new ManagedIdentityCredential());
    options.Connect(new Uri(AppConfigurationEndpoint), tokenCredential)
        .Select("SharepointFileTransfer:*", "dev");
});
Configuration = builder.Build();



I don't know how to use the managed identity from there


To use the managed identity, you can use azure VM as the self-hosted agent,  so that you can have the managed identity enabled on the agent.

Assign the Managed Identity to Azure App Configuration, and give the App Configuration Data Reader role to the managed identity.

Please check doc to use the managed identity in your Unit test project.


Please refer to the links below for more detail：
Use managed identities to access App Configuration
Running Unit Test Projects with Azure App Configuration in Azure DevOps Pipeline
